# How to get the return of a class method printed in main in Java?

Tags: java, class, constructor, return

I am just learning now class and constructors in Java but I can't understand why I can't print out a combined value from other methods. This is my code in main.java :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Wall height = new Wall ();
    Wall width = new Wall ();
    Wall area = new Wall();


    height.setHeight(5);
    System.out.println("height = " + height.getHeight());
    width.setWidth(4);
    System.out.println("width = " +width.getWidth());
    System.out.println("area = " +width.getWidth()*height.getHeight());
    System.out.println(area.getArea());
    System.out.println("AREA      =     " + area );

}
```

and this is my code in Wall Class :

```
public class Wall {

private double height;
private double width;

public Wall () {
    this.height = height;
    this width = width;
}

    public Wall (double height, double width){
        if (height <= 0 || width <= 0) {
            this.height = 0;
            this.width = 0;
        }

    }

        public double getHeight () {
            return this.height;
        }
        public double getWidth () {
            return this.width;
        }
        public void setHeight (double height){
        this.height = height;
    }
    public void setWidth (double width){
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getArea () {
        this.height = height;
        this width = width;
    double area = getHeight()*getWidth();

        return area;
    }
```

I have problems with the last method getArea, as it prints out 0.0 as if height and width are not set. What am I missing?

Comment: Your `getArea()` method has some weirdness in it: What is with the 1st two lines of that method? They don't do anything useful and only will confuse. Get rid of them.

Comment: Also, you're setting the height and width for 2 completely different Wall objects, and this will have no effect on the state of the 3rd Wall object, area. You need to create one single Wall object, not three, set the height and width of this object and area will work.

Comment: yes I just added them to make sure IntelliJ understands are the same value, as I tried anything else but no change. Removed them, same problem.

Comment: else the third object area, I added it just trying to fix my issue but I still can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

You have set `width` and `height` in different objects and trying to find the
the area from a different object.

## Solution

You need to set these values to the same object as shown below:

```
Wall wall = new Wall ();

wall.setHeight(5);
System.out.println("height = " + wall.getHeight());
wall.setWidth(4);
System.out.println("width = " + wall.getWidth());
System.out.println("area = " + wall.getWidth() * wall.getHeight());
System.out.println(wall.getArea());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three different `Wall` objects - the `area` won't be affected by setting values on `height` or `width`. It seems like you meant to have one wall:

```
Wall wall = new Wall();

wall.setHeight(5);
System.out.println("height = " + wall.getHeight());
wall.setWidth(4);
System.out.println("width = " +wall.getWidth());
System.out.println("area = " + wall.getWidth() * wall.getHeight());
System.out.println(wall.getArea());
```

Comment: yes now it works I can't believe it was something so easy!!!!